# How do I return one of multiple types that implement a non-object-safe trait?

Tags: rust

I want a function that returns multiple types of `Range`s (e.g. `Range`, `RangeFrom`, `RangeTo`). My goal is to check whether values are within ranges which we don't know at compile time if they are open or closed.

I tried to do this by specifying the return type of `RangeBounds`. Unfortunately, because `.contains` is generic, I don't think that's possible.

Is there another way? Or should I just pass around `(Option<isize>, Option<isize>)`, and check values against them manually?

This question is broader than explaining this specific error - I'm trying to find if there's another way of accomplishing the goal. I want to use the standard libraries `Range` tools rather than a custom implementation.

```rust
use std::ops::{Range, RangeBounds};

fn range(start: Option<isize>, end: Option<isize>) -> dyn RangeBounds<isize> {
    match (start, end) {
        (Some(s), Some(e)) => Range { s, e },
        // other options here
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

Causes:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `std::ops::RangeBounds` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/lib.rs:3:1
  |
3 | fn range(start: Option<isize>, end: Option<isize>) -> dyn RangeBounds<isize> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::RangeBounds` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: method `contains` has generic type parameters
```

Another approach that doesn't work:

```rust
use std::ops::{Range, RangeBounds, RangeFrom, RangeTo};
fn range(start: Option<isize>, end: Option<isize>) -> impl RangeBounds<isize> {
    match (start, end) {
        (Some(s), Some(e)) => Range { start: s, end: e },
        (Some(s), None) => RangeFrom { start: s },
        // other options here
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:18:28
   |
16 | /     match (start, end) {
17 | |         (Some(s), Some(e)) => Range { start: s, end: e  },
   | |                               --------------------------- this is found to be of type `std::ops::Range<isize>`
18 | |         (Some(s), None) => RangeFrom { start: s },
   | |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::ops::Range`, found struct `std::ops::RangeFrom`
19 | |         // other options here
20 | |         _ => panic!(),
21 | |     }
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
```

Comment: Thanks for edits @Shepmaster

Comment: Your second example doesn't work because `impl Trait` as the return type [cannot be used for multiple conditional types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001592/1233251).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You **cannot** return a trait object for traits that are not object-safe. This is thoroughly explained already:

- [The trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45116984/155423)
- [Why does a generic method inside a trait require trait object to be sized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42620022/155423)
- [What is the cited problem with using generic type parameters in trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57252674/155423)

Instead, define your own object-safe trait and implement it in terms of the non-object-safe one:

```
use std::ops::{Range, RangeBounds};

trait MyBounds {
    fn contains(&self, v: &isize) -> bool;
}

impl<T> MyBounds for T
where
    T: RangeBounds<isize>,
{
    fn contains(&self, v: &isize) -> bool {
        RangeBounds::contains(self, v)
    }
}

fn range(start: Option<isize>, end: Option<isize>) -> Box<dyn MyBounds> {
    match (start, end) {
        (Some(start), Some(end)) => Box::new(Range { start, end }),
        // other options here
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Create an Object-safe Trait in Rust with a method that accepts a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46235975/155423)
- [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001592/155423)
- [Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29760668/155423)
- [How do I return an instance of a trait from a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30661046/155423)